# Custom Permissions in a Document Library

Tags: 2013, document-library, permissions, document

Is it possible within a document library to have custom permissions based on file metadata.

So for example within one document library you add multiple files and against each file you assign a customer name. Is it feasible to have permission groups set up by customer, so if you're in the respective customer group you can then see or edit the files related to that customer (which would be identified by the file metadata), but not any of the others.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A very reasonable and practical request!  From my knowledge SharePoint doesn't provide a direct way to accomplish this task, but you may be able to get around it by using a content query or list filter to display only those results that the user should see.  Another option would be to create a workflow when the item is created to grant item level permissions to the users in the customer group.  This would break inheritance though.

Answer (score 0):

I would create folders and set the appropriate permissions on the folder level, then all the files in the folder inherit those permissions. You could do it in an even receiver on itemadded to break permission inheritance, but that would get messy if you have a lot of files.

I'd stick to folder based permissions where each customer has their own folder. You can continue to have the customer field to further classify the documents inside.

Answer (score 0):

Field level permissions are not possible in SharePoint either by OOTB and you need to build a custom solution for that.

Pls refer the below references. [Link-1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73106/field-level-permission-development)

[Link-2](http://sharepointpromag.com/blog/3-approaches-restricting-access-sharepoint-columns-and-metadata)